# TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'store.navigationRef.isReady') expo

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo, monorepo

I am trying to use expo router in my expo project configured in a nx mono repo. I was able to get the app up and running adding all the necessary configuration. However i keep getting this error

```
 TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'store.navigationRef.isReady')
```

when i am using a Link to navigate.

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "mobile",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-native": "*",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "*",
    "metro-config": "*",
    "react-native": "*",
    "expo": "*",
    "react-native-svg": "*",
    "react-native-web": "*",
    "@nx/expo": "*",
    "@expo/metro-config": "*",
    "react-native-svg-transformer": "*",
    "react": "*",
    "expo-splash-screen": "~0.20.5",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.6.0",
    "expo-dev-client": "^2.4.11",
    "expo-dev-menu-interface": "^1.3.0",
    "expo-dev-launcher": "^2.4.13",
    "expo-updates-interface": "^0.10.1",
    "expo-manifests": "^0.7.2",
    "expo-dev-menu": "^3.2.1",
    "@babel/core": "*",
    "tslib": "*",
    "@apollo/client": "*",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.7",
    "redux": "^4.2.1",
    "react-redux": "^8.1.3",
    "expo-router": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "4.6.3",
    "react-native-screens": "~3.22.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "~2.12.0",
    "expo-linking": "~5.0.2",
    "expo-constants": "~14.4.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "eas-build-pre-install": "cd ../../ && node tools/scripts/eas-build-pre-install.mjs . apps/mobile && cp package-lock.json apps/mobile",
    "eas-build-post-install": "cd ../../ && node tools/scripts/eas-build-post-install.mjs . apps/mobile",
    "android": "expo run:android",
    "ios": "expo run:ios"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0"
  }
}
```

babel.config.js

```
process.env.EXPO_ROUTER_APP_ROOT = '../../src/index.js';
module.exports = function (api) {
  api.cache(true);
  return {
    presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
    plugins: [
      ["module:react-native-dotenv", {
        "moduleName": "@env",
        "path": "env/.env",
      },
        'expo-router/babel'
      ]
    ]
  };
};
```

index.js

```
import { registerRootComponent } from 'expo';

import App from './src/app';

// registerRootComponent calls AppRegistry.registerComponent('main', () => App);
// It also ensures that whether you load the app in Expo Go or in a native build,
// the environment is set up appropriately
registerRootComponent(App);
```

app/index.tsx

```
import React, { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet,
  ScrollView,
  View,
  Text,
  StatusBar,
  TouchableOpacity,
  Linking,
} from 'react-native';
import Svg, { Path } from 'react-native-svg';
import { color } from '@test-repo/theme';
import {APP_NAME} from '@env';
import { ApolloProvider } from  '@apollo/client';
import {client} from "@test-repo/network";
import { MovieScreen } from './MovieScreen';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { store } from './store/store';
import { Link } from 'expo-router';


export const App = () => {
  const [whatsNextYCoord, setWhatsNextYCoord] = useState<number>(0);
  const scrollViewRef = useRef<null | ScrollView>(null);

  return (
<SafeAreaView>
    <Link href={"/"}>
       <Text>
  Refresh screen
  </Text>
    </Link>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
```

Anything i am doing wrong?